# How to create colored squares board in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to create a board with colored squares. The point is that I want to have an array with for example 4 colors and I need to fill every square with random color from that array.

Right now I generate n random colors (colors.js file)

```
export const randomUpTo = (max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
};

const randomColor = () => {
  const r = randomUpTo(255);
  const g = randomUpTo(255);
  const b = randomUpTo(255);
  return `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
};

export const generateColors = (n) => {
  return Array.from(new Array(n), randomColor);
};
```

...and I display n different sqaures in Board.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { generateColors } from "../../utils/colors";
import "./Board.css";

class Board extends Component {
  state = {
    colors: generateColors(12)
  };
    
  render() {
    const { colors } = this.state;

    const squares = colors.map((color, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index} className="square" style={{ background: color }}></div>
      );
    });

    return <div className="squares">{squares}</div>;
  }
}

export default Board;
```

but it's wrong because I create n (12 in this case) squares and fill them with n (12 in this case) colors. I need to have an array of colors (for example colors = [black, white, blue, green]) and fill n squares (12 in this case) with random color from this array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `colors` is an *array* of colors, not a single color. So you would have to get the particular color e.g. by *index*.

```
const squares = colors.map((color, index) => {
   const color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
                             // or dynamically   * colors.length
   return (
       <div key={index} className="square" style={{ background: color }}></div>
   );
});
```

Comment: Yes but I have 12 colors and I map through that 12 colors which creates 12 different squares. I need 12 squares from for example 4 colors from array